# Robolectric test compiling classes for each run

Tags: android, robolectric

In my project, one robolectric(v3.1.2) test is taking 30 seconds to run when executed from Android Studio. When profiled, much of the time is spent on :app:compile*JavaWithJavac task. This task is executed even when no change is made to the code. Is this the expected behaviour? Because roblectric test should be fast, and in our case its not serving the purpose.

Comment: Are you sure it is Robolectric?

Comment: @EugenMartynov haha.. it is Robolectric..